# create array of pointers to files

Tags: c, file, io, argv

How would I go about making an array of file pointers in C?
I would like to create an array of file pointers to the arguments of main... like a1.txt, a2.txt, etc... So I would run `./prog arg1.txt arg2.txt arg3.txt`to have the program use these files.
Then the argument for main is `char **argv`

From argv, I would like to create the array of files/file pointers. This is what I have so far.

```
FILE *inputFiles[argc - 1];
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    inputFiles[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r");
```

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with it.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is fine, but remember to compile in C99.

If you don't use C99, you need to create the array on heap, like:

```
FILE** inputFiles = malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * (argc-1));

// operations...

free(inputFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks. So just for testing sake, how would I print the names of the files that the array pointers point to?

Comment: @Hristo - there is no way to recover the name of the file from the FILE*.  But since you have the argv array, the file name of inputFiles[n] can be found at argv[n].

Comment: yes, i have the names of the files stored in another array, i was just wondering if I can do it the other way. I'm new to C, this is my 4th week :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>`

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *inputFiles[argc - 1];
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    inputFiles[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    printf("%p\n",inputFiles[i]);
}
  return 0;
}
```

It prints different pointers for each file pointer along with the names.  Allowing OS to close files properly :)

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense!