# Handling an array of FILE in C

Tags: c

I need to modify a program written in C, which I have very little experience with and I would like to handle an array of files. However, I am experiencing a problem of handling with pointers when I want to write into these files...

Here's the minimal code to see what I want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(FILE *f){
    fprintf(f, "test\n");
}

void func_1(FILE *f){
    fprintf(f[0], "test\n");
}

void func_2(FILE *f){
    fprintf(f[0][0], "test\n");
}

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    func_1(f);
    fclose(f);

    FILE *f_1[2];
    f_1[0] = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    f_1[1] = fopen("test_2.txt", "w");
    func_1(f_1);
    fclose(f_1[0]);
    fclose(f_1[1]);

    FILE *f_2[2][2];
    fprintf(f[0][0], "test\n");
    f_2[0][0] = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    f_2[1][1] = fopen("test_2.txt", "w");
    func_2(f_2);
    fclose(f_2[0][0]);
    fclose(f_2[1][1]);
}
```

Basically, the first part with f is working but not when I am creating f_1 or f_2 which are arrays of files.
How to handle them to write into some of them specifically.

Sincerely,
Paul

EDIT: As noted my minimal code is not running and is confusing. It is my bad, I continue on trying other things and forgot to remove the test modifications.

Comment: It's unclear why you need two-dimensional arrays for this.

Comment: `f[0,0]` is the same as `f[0]`. Please enable compiler warnings and listen to them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? What exactly is the expected behavior and actual behavior?

Comment: func_1(f_1); and  fprintf(f[0,0], "test\n"); and func_2(f_2); are not correct.  your program will not compile

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242901/create-array-of-pointers-to-files

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple `func` functions, You just need a single function that takes a FILE* array and an index.  Individual files are passed as `FILE*`, so an array of files is passed as `FILE**`.

```
void func(FILE** file_array, unsigned int index) {
    FILE* f = file_array[index];
    if (f)
    {
        fprintf(f, "test\n");
    }
}
```

Then to invoke:

```
FILE *files[2];
files[0] = fopen("test.txt", "w");
files[1] = fopen("test_2.txt", "w");
func(files,0);
func(files,1);
fclose(files[0]);
fclose(files[1]);
```

You can also invoke `func` when all you have is a single `FILE*` instance.  That is:

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
func(&f, 0);
```

For your 2-d array, I'm not sure what you are wanting.  But this:

```
FILE *f_2[2][2];
fprintf(f[0][0], "test\n");
```

Is undefined behavior.  You are invoking `fprintf` with an uninitialized file handle.